# Can Dragon Video play upnp videos?

Tags: kubuntu, video-streaming, upnp, dragon

I have Plex and minidlna streaming videos via upnp and wondering if there is a way to play my videos on Dragon Video player?

If not, is there a better KDE Application to stream videos?

Answer (score 0):

the '**djmount**' package will let you mount dlna/upnp servers to a local directory and the contents will appear as local files  you can then play.  This should let any video player access the files as if they were on the local machine.

Ive only toyed with it a little bit but it does seem to work for my anime.

djmount (source: djmount): file system client for mounting network media servers. In component universe, is optional. Version 0.71-6 (raring), package size 66 kB, installed size 163 kB

its homepage with guides and docs   http://djmount.sourceforge.net/